# ReactJs can't get async content form api call in useEffect and use it later in component

Tags: reactjs, async-await, fetch-api, use-effect

I'm lost. I've tried almost all I know. In my other component, similar process works fine, but in this one there is something obviously wrong implemented.
I have a **Context Provider**, and set two values to share, a function to call an Api and retrieve a list of contacts (`getContactsList`), and a variable where I put that list of contacts (`contactsList`).
I call `getContactsList` in `useEffect`. Later, I can use `contactsList` variable, but is always an empty array. I know that the problem is related to Promises and async functions maybe, but I can't find the mistake in my code.

I left here a copy of the  components, starting for the view component that has the problem:

**Detail Component:**

```
function ContactDetail() {
    
    const { getContactsList, contactsList } = useContext(ContactsContext);
    const { id } = useParams();
    useEffect(() => { getContactsList().catch(null) }, []);

    const contact = contactsList?.filter(c => {
        return (Number(c.id) === Number(id))
    });

    return (
        <div>
            {contact? "contact finded" : "contact not finded"}
        </div>
    );
}
```

**ApiCall**

```
async function apiCall (
    url,
    method = "get",
    body,
    headers)
    {
       try {
           const response = await fetch(url, {
            method,
            body,
            headers
        });

        const r = await response.json();
        return r;
    }
    catch (err) {
        Promise.reject(err);
    }
    }
```

**Provider**

```
function ContactsProvider({ children }) {

    const [ contactsList,setContactsList ] = useState([]);

    const getContactsList = async () => {
        try {
            const contactsResult = await apiCall("https://fakeurl.com");
            setContactsList(contactsResult);
        }
        catch(err) {
            setContactsList([]);
        }};

    return (
        <ContactsContext.Provider value={{getContactsList, contactsList}}>
            {children}
        </ContactsContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

Also, the code is in my GitHub: https://github.com/thenablyn/local-search-browser.git

Comment: It is recommended here on SO that you create a _minimal_ reproducible example. Meaning, it would be very helpful if you'd reduce your code as much as possible so we don't have to spend so much time trying to deduce what's going on.

Comment: Sorry. I thought exactly the opposite (my mistake). Thought that count with the complete information would be useful for the analysis. Thanks for your feedback on that!

Comment: No problem. Reading this will help you understand how to write questions with good form: [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that I forgot to get the first element when I did the array.filter() method. It's a Jr mistake.

The code in that assignment has to be like this:

```
const [contact] = contactsList.filter(...); //this get the first element and assign to constant "contact"
```

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't seem to be in your repo, but I've tested what you've written and it seems to work, is there a chance the `id` coming from useParams isn't matching any of the contacts when you're filtering?

Comment: Sorry! I've just push a commit with all the changes. The ID exist in the retrieved array. I'm using a public API for testing (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users). You can see there are ID's from 1 to 10.

Comment: I think the problem is that getContactsList method is not saving, somehow, the retrieved array in contactsList variable by the time I'm reading it